# windows grep redirect output to file

Tags: windows, grep, io-redirection

I'm working on windows and I want to find all the strings beetwen quotes, from a directory. For example, if I have this:

```
string s = "Hello World!"
```

The grep command should return me "Hello World!".
Here is how I do this:

```
grep -Roe \"[^\"]*\" directory
```

I need to redirect the output to a file but when I redirect the output, like this "grep -Roe \"[^\"]*\" directory > log" I get the following errors:

```
>: Invalid argument
log: No such file or directory
```

Do you know how can I solve this and redirect the output?

Comment: You need to create a file named `log` first and then redirect the output.

Comment: I tried this, but the first error persists.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question, and by now the OP has probably solved it... but for posterity, it's worth noting that the issue is to do with the compiler conventions (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/358550/cant-pipe-or-redirect-cygwin-grep-output), and find the answer headed "**You aren't using a Unix shell. Quoting is different**").

As you've discovered, while your expression will work fine at the command line, when it is used in conjunction with a redirect it gets parsed wrongly.

The solution is to escape the double quotes with a caret (`^`), not a backslash (`\`). And you need to escape the caret as well (with a caret). You should also enclose the entire search expression in single quotes.

Reformulating your command using caret-escaping (and enclosing in `''`) yields

```
grep -Roe '^"[^^^"]*^"' directory > log
```

I use this quite a bit to get style attributes from legacy HTML files (basically stuff written by a former coder who didn't believe much in separating content from presentation) - in which case I use

```
grep -iown 'style=^"[^^^"]*^"' index.html > styles.txt
```

It works like a charm.

Imagine a code repository where every in HTML file, even the `p` tags go something like `<p style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px; font: normal 12px Arial; color#FFFFFF">`. Sheesh.